# Non static method cannot be referenced from a static context: Id AutocreatedConfigSelfReg

Tags: apex, customer-community

I'm currently working on a Salesforce Community and used the 'Create a configurable self-reg handler' so I could map an existing contact to my user instead of creating a generic user. The default Apex class createUser method definition is the following one:

```
    global Id createUser(Id accountId, Id profileId, Map<SObjectField, String> registrationAttributes, String password) {
```

Since I added my own code to map the proper contact to my user, I need to create a test class to push my updated class in production. Below is code for my test class where I call the createUser method that was generated:

```
public with sharing class selfRegistrationTEST {

public static void selfRegistrationTest() {

    Schema.DescribeFieldResult F = User.Email.getDescribe();
    Schema.sObjectField T = F.getSObjectField();

    Map<SObjectField, String> m1;
    m1.put(T, 'customer@email.com'); 

    Id userId = AutocreatedConfigSelfReg123456789.createUser('accountIdhere', 'profileIdhere', m1, null);

}
```

However, I'm receiving the following error message which seems related to the Map I'm trying to use as an input variable.

```
Non static method cannot be referenced from a static context: Id AutocreatedConfigSelfReg123456789.createUser(Id, Id, Map<Schema.SObjectField,String>, String)
```

I researched this error and could not determine what was causing it or how I could resolve it so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your apex class looks something like this:

```
global class AutocreatedConfigSelfReg implements Auth.ConfigurableSelfRegHandler { 

    global Id createUser(Id accountId, Id profileId, Map<SObjectField, String> registrationAttributes, String password) {
            //Some bla bla coce
    }
}
```

`createUser` is an instance method, ie you can only invoke it using an instance.

Fix Create an instance of `AutocreatedConfigSelfReg123456789` using `new AutocreatedConfigSelfReg123456789()` and then call create user method

```
public with sharing class selfRegistrationTEST {

public static void selfRegistrationTest() {

    Schema.DescribeFieldResult F = User.Email.getDescribe();
    Schema.sObjectField T = F.getSObjectField();

    Map<SObjectField, String> m1;
    m1.put(T, 'customer@email.com'); 

    Id userId = new AutocreatedConfigSelfReg123456789().createUser('accountIdhere', 'profileIdhere', m1, null);

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Pranay, that resolved my issue